# Why does $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x+h) = f(x)$ according to Lang's Short Calculus?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

On Chapter III (*Derivatives*), section 5 (*Sums, products, & quotients*) of Lang's *Short Calculus*, Lang writes the following excerpt:

> [image]

It's unclear to me why Lang asserts $$f(x+h) = f(x) + h \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $$

From independent research, I know this is true if the function is continuous (https://www.quora.com/Does-Lim-f-x+h-f-x-as-h-approaches-0). However, my question is how did Lang arrive at this assertion (aka why is the assertion true)? Thanks.

Comment: You making the assumption Lang is talking about the limit of the equation.  He's not.  He's talking about the *actual* equation when $h \ne 0$.  Then he's using that this basic equality is true for all $h \ne 0$ then when he *does* talk about the limit he can assume that it is true for the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Lang states $f(x+h) = f(x) + h \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ he isn't talking about limits.  He's talking about an actual real measurable non-zero number, $h$.

And it's true: $f(x+k) = f(x) + k \frac{f(x+k)-f(x)}{k}= f(x) + k\frac{f(x+k)}k - k\frac {f(x)}{k} = f(x) + f(x+k) - f(x) = f(x+k)$

His point is that *BECAUSE* $f(x+k) = f(x) + k \frac{f(x+k)-f(x)}{k}$ for all $k \ne 0$ then *IF* $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ has a limit.  We know $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(x + h) =$

$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}(f(x) + h \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h})=$

$f(x) +  \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}h* \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=$

$f(x) + 0*f'(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! While Yaddle clarified the point of difficulty in the question most directly, you identified and resolved my underlying misconception (that Lang was talking about limits). I think your clarification will help me (and others) go a long way.

Answer (score 2):

You get 
$$f(x) + h \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = f(x) + (f(x+h)-f(x)) = f(x+h)$$
just by calculating it directly. There is no other argument than pure algebra here (multiplication and addition). I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

If $c\not=0$, then

$$a+c{b-a\over c}=a+{c\over c}(b-a)=a+(b-a)=b$$

is an algebraic identity.  Now let $a=f(x)$, $b=f(x+h)$, and $c=h$.